# ASP.Net MVC3 Controller "globals"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to have this code run for each of my actions in one of my controllers. How can I do this without having to copy the code for each of the actions?  Is there an init method for the controller?

```
System.Web.HttpSessionStateBase Sess = HttpContext.Session;
string pid = (Sess["PID"] != null ? Sess["PID"].ToString() : "");
string LogonTicket = (Sess["LogonTicket"] != null ? Sess["LogonTicket"].ToString() : "");
```

Comment: What do you want to do with those `pid` and `logonTicket` variables? The code you have shown only reads them from the session but I guess there's more to it that you haven't shown.

Comment: Yes they'll be used elsewhere in the actions to retrieve info and set the action View's Viewbag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you wrap this up into properties in a base controller?

```
class abstract YourControllerBase : Controller
{
   public string Pid { get { ... } }
   public string LogonTicket { get { ... } }
}
```

Comment: How would I reference them in inherited controllers?

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options:

1. Put the code in the constructor
2. Use OnActionExecuting

   ```
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
       base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I think although being abolutely correct, abstract classes and inheritance-based answers make an "asker" feel uncomfortable, since he is trying to work on an even simpler case then inheritace.

A short answer - just put the code into the constructor of the controller.

For example:

```
public HomeController: Controller {

    private string _pid;
    private string _logonTicket;

    public HomeController() {

        System.Web.HttpSessionStateBase Sess = HttpContext.Session;

        _pid = (Sess["PID"] != null ? Sess["PID"].ToString() : "");
        _logonTicket = (Sess["LogonTicket"] != null ? Sess["LogonTicket"].ToString() : "");
    }


//REST OF YOUR CONTROLLER CODE

}
```

Now you can access `_pid` and `_logonTicket` from controller action's code.

Comment: Since I need them in other controllers, too, I'm going to use @Daniel A. White's suggestion to put them in a base controller.

Comment: No problem, my answer only has meaning in case you didn't want to bother with abstract class at that point. If you are fine - properties is the best and elegant way to go.